# Rocket-chat: Any way to find messages, in a channel, that are made by me?

Tags: rocket.chat

I can search in rocket-chat by username, but that shows only messages that have the username tagged, not the messages created by the username. Is there a way to find messages that were created by a username?

Comment: Currently im pretty sure there is no way of doing that in rocket.chat, maybe request a feature in its [repo](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to the search button in the flextab and type in ->  from:[username]